# What's a good way to raise a child that is too powerful for you, while minimally hurting yourself or others?

Tags: society, magic, politics

Normal babies have temper tantrums. Magic babies burn down the house. As much as one tries, babies and children won't stay happy forever. What's the best way to raise a magic/quirk/mutant child with love when natural temper tantrums could have the power to injure?

Comment: A good answer requires some additional precision on your part. Can the child access the powers instinctively from birth? If so, how powerful do they start and how quickly do they increase? A magic baby that can make a candle-sized flame is one thing, a magic baby that can make a flamethrower-sized flame is a different story entirely. A baby that doesn't start setting things on fire until age 3 or 4 is a completely different third thing.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you specify the superpowers / magic involved? It's hard to defend against an unidentified weapon.

Comment: Euthanasia is the merciful way to go.

Comment: More info would be welcome.  Since it stands as a very general question right now, more detail would be very nice.  I threw together an answer based on the limited info, but more detail would help folks give you a variety iof stuff to choose from.

Comment: The Twilight Zone asked this question in 1961: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_a_Good_Life_(The_Twilight_Zone)

Answer (score 3):

If you suspect your child of being a mutant with powers and you cannot afford to hire Edna Mode for her services, you may have some problems.

You are going to have to adjust as the kid grows and you pin down the powers a little better but there are places you can start.

The first thing I would do is move way out into the middle of nowhere.  Like Nevada, or New Mexico.  Maybe the Bisti Badlands or Area 51.  The last thing you need is a lot civilians nearby.  Civilians can be rather breakable.

Since you would be in the desert Southwest, Adobe would be a decent material to begin with. Traditional adobe is good at insulation for those harsh heat filled summers.  Instead of the normal wood  supports for the ceiling, switch to steel.  If a small angry human flamethrower is about, you would be asking for trouble with the traditional stuff.  You could do some hybrid stuff by making the walls adobe and then do the ceiling with Catalan (or Timbrel) vaulting.  Roof from ceramic (fireproof) tile that needs minimal internal support.

So you have a relatively fireproof structure and less opportunity for collateral damage, that covers a lot of what you might worry about.  The next is to make sure your house is on large plot of land so you can bring in a tractor and create some very wide firebreaks.  That way if the flammable tot is outside, the risk of a wildfire goes down somewhat.  The location and large lot should also mean little air traffic in case the youngster is inclined to flight, literally.

You are also going to want the home to be as off-grid as possible.  Lots and lots of solar and wind power, because you need to heat the house with electricity rather than flammable gasses.  Also, if you are off grid and you misjudge the power and it turns out to be electric powers instead of fire, you are isolated from the grid at large so there is no opportunity for hi-jinks there.  Also, internet should be by line of sight wireless for the same reason.  No wires.

Obviously you want water to be readily available for fire suppression.  Standard sprinkler setups are your friend there.

This gives you a starting point.  Then you can hire Edna when you figure out a way to afford her frighteningly high hourly rate.  In the meantime, make sure your health insurance is paid up.

Comment: "_The first thing I would do is move way out into the middle of nowhere._" I'm going to hazard a guess that you don't have any children. Because if you have no access to babysitters, the prospect of your infant lightning-bolting you will seem positively merciful.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Actually I have three, all boys, and 2 are now out of the house.  I'm looking to protect the kid, as any good parent would.  The parents would, of course go slowly nuts.  Going nuts is not a function of available babysitters though.  It's going to happen once the child is born.  babysitters may help slow the process. but it cannot be stopped.  I myself am quite insane.  I am positively giddy with the prospect of my first grandchild.  then I wilL be able to watch one of my boys descent into madness.  BUWAHAHAHAHA